# Error 500 when goin to wp-admin (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to  complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of  the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this  error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

As you can see, i can't get into my admin CP. localhost works fine, the trouble comes when i visit localhost/wp-admin. I was trying out [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-change-the-admin-url-or-wp-admin-to-secure-login?replies=13https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-change-the-admin-url-or-wp-admin-to-secure-login?replies=13) guide, but when it didn't work, i just deleted what i copy pasted. I'm on space bound, and hope here would be a good soul to help me out.

Regards.

Comment: sounds like a botched .htaccess file - maybe post it so we can take a look? Notify me in a comment if you do.

Comment: Thanks, @enigma. Founded my .htaccess in admin folder, and removed the line! Works like a charm, thank you so much!